# Projection of from a point to a line of a rational conic

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to follow the projection of the conic $C = x^2 - y^2 = z^2$ from the point $(1:0:1)$ to the line $x=0$

I follow the generation of the regular function $\phi$ for the projection and can see why this is represented by $(y:z-x)$

I also see how this has a regular representation on the conic itself as $(z+x: -y)$ which is regular when restricted to $C$.

This gives us a regular map of the projection at all points of $C$.

The next step is to show that it's surjective, and for this I'm given that we have a point
$$
Q = \left(1 - \frac{2}{1-a^2}: \frac{2a}{1-a^2}:1\right)
$$
such that $Q$ lies in the affinisation of $C$ in $\mathbb{A}^2_{z \neq 0}$ and $\phi(Q) = (1:a)$ for $a \neq \pm 1$. The remaining points are dealt with separately and I can see how that works as well, and I'm comfortable with the proof of injectivity.

The derivation of $Q$, however, ruins me. I have sat here with pen and paper for hours. I can, of course, see that it works, but I cannot reverse engineer it in any natural and obvious way that would help me complete a similar exercise. What am I missing?

Comment: It's a rational parametrization derived by looking at the intersection of the line $y=a(x+1)$ with the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\omega=(1:0:1)$ be  the projection centre.
I) We have a rational map from the projective plane $\mathbb P^2$ to to the $Y$ axis $L:X=0$ which is regular outside of $\omega$ and is described by the morphism $$\pi:\mathbb P^2\setminus \{\omega\}\to L:(x:y:z)\mapsto (0:y:z-x)$$ 
This morphism cannot be extended through its pole $\omega$, **but** the restriction $\pi\vert C\setminus \{\omega\}$ can be extended to a morphism, actually an isomorphism, $\; p:C\stackrel {\sim}{\to} L$ satisfying $$ p(x:y:z)= (0:y:z-x)=(0:v:w) \; \operatorname {for} \; (x:y:z)\neq (1:0:1)=\omega \\
p(x:y:z)=(0:x+z:-y)=(0:v:w) \; \operatorname {for}\; (x:y:z)\neq (-1:0:1)=\omega' $$ In particular $p(\omega)=(0:2:0)=(0:1:0)$.

II) In order to calculate   $p^{-1}:L \stackrel {\sim}{\to} C$ we compute that the line through $(0:v:w)$ and $\omega$ has equation $$vX+wY-vZ=0$$  Its intersection with $C$ is obtained by solving the system $$vX+wY-vZ=0\\ X^2-Y^2-Z^2=0$$ 
a) If $w=1$ we get the system $$Y=v(Z-X)\\ X^2-v^2(Z-X)^2-Z^2=(X-Z)[X+Z-v^2(X-Z)]      =0$$ Its solutions are
(i)   $(X:Y:Z)=(1:0:1)=\omega$ (of course!) for $X-Z=0$
(ii) For $X-Z\neq0$ we get the desired formula  $$p^{-1}(0:v:1)=(v^2+1:-2v:v^2-1)$$ b) And  finally for $w=0$, we have $p^{-1}(0:1:0)=\omega=(1:0:1)$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the line through $(1,0)$ having slope $-a$.  The equation of the line is $y=-a(x-1)$.  We'd like to find the second point of intersection of the line with the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1$, the first being $(1,0)$.

\begin{align*}
x^2 - \left(-a(x-1)\right)^2 &= 1 \\
x^2 - a^2 x^2 + 2a^2x-a^2 & =1 \\
(1-a^2)x^2 +2a^2x -(1+a^2) & = 0 \\
x^2 +\frac{2a^2}{1-a^2}x - \frac{1+a^2}{1-a^2} &= 0 \\ 
\end{align*}
Now $x=1$ is a root of the quadratic, so the other root must be $-\dfrac{1+a^2}{1-a^2} = 1-\dfrac{2}{1-a^2}$  Plugging this back into $y=-a(x-1)$ 
\begin{align*}
 y &= -a(x-1) \\ 
y &= -a\left(1-\frac{2}{1-a^2} -1\right) \\
 y &= \frac{2a}{1-a^2} \\ 
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks! - Incidentally I meant to write $\phi(Q) = (a:1)$ up there - typo that I just noticed but it actually makes more sense that way. So presumably you can either see this geometrically as a parametrisation, or note algebriacally that it arises out of the regular function for the mapping - because if the point $(a:1)$ (loosely) is some $(y: x-1)$ then we have that $x-1 = 1$ and $y = a.1$, yes?